# Issue with facebook permissions review and different hashkey/google play package name

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

Recently i submitted my android app through facebook review for the permissions of publish_actions, user_birthday, user_location.

After 2 days my request was approved but when i tried to use it at the app with a developer account i was still getting the alerts saying "Submit for Login Review Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by facebook". If i used a non developer account then the app was crashing.

This makes me wonder.Is there some time needed before the permissions are pushed to production? Do i need to do something to accept the approval?

I am asking cause i was seeing the permissions at the results of last submissions but not in the approval area (first pic) but not in the approved permissions area (second pic).
[image: Needed permissions seems to be approved]
[image: But do not appear in the approved area]

An issue that might occurred is that i submitted for review an apk that was signed with the debug keystore and had slightly different Google play package name. Also it had different version code.
More specifically the submitted for review apk had com.dummy.android as google play package name and the release apk that i tried the priviledges and failed had com.dummy.android.release as google play package name.

But this is odd as you can modify both google play package name and hashkeys after the approval.

Maybe i need to submit an apk for approval in every release i make as the version code changes? I've seen from the logs that the following are sent to the facebook api call: google package name, version code, hashkey.

The even more strange thing is that even the APK that i submitted for review was showing the "submit for login review" notification on login for the permissions i was just granted.

This happened for 4 hours after i got the approval for facebook. 
Not wanting to lose more time i submitted the same app for review for the same actions and i am waiting.
After i did that the granted permissions stopped appearing as granted anywhere in the settings.

Any ideas why this might happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that:

**1.** you have correctly generated the app-id with OpenSSL and declared it in your application manifest.

**2.** application package name and app-id are correctly entered on your Facebook app details page.

**3.** you have applied for the relevant permissions and received them from FB.

**4.** the access token is valid (i.e. non-null).

**5.** the session state of the access token is OPENED.

The package name has to be exactly the same as that posted in your FB app developer settings when you applied for permissions and received them, so keep the app namespace as `com.dummy.android`. When you create a release APK, that has to be signed with OpenSSL **AGAIN**, and the new id has to be updated in your FB developer settings.

Please post the logcat error which occurs when you use the non-developer account, this will also help us identify the problem.

Comment: @paptom: are you still facing a problem ? Do let me know ... :)

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your answer. Answering point by point:

Point 1:
By “generate app_id” i guess you mean generate key hash right? The app_id that is added to the android manifest is static it is a long number and remains the same always. Am i correct?
Regarding key hash i use this method http://stackoverflow.com/a/13488560/1244978 to programmatically generate the key hash (also described here at the bottom https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)

Comment: Point 2:
The google package name was not the same on the initial submission from the one we use (so maybe that was the problem). A point to take into consideration is that we use gradle to generate and sign the release apk and thus a postfix is added to the package name making it 
com.dummy.android.release(That means that the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml is different from the one that gets created on release by a difference of .release). We know have added com.dummy.android.release to the settings. 
Do you see any issues with that?

Comment: Point 3:
We are sure about that

Point 4:
We are sure about that as we login properly.

Point 5:
We are sure about that as we login properly.

How do you explain that we can login properly but we cannot take the granted permissions? If we had the wrong keyhash then we will not login at all. Correct?
Maybe now that we have sent for review the apk with the correct hashkey and package name we will be luckier? I am asking cause we will have to wait another two days to know if it worked :/

Adding logcat bellow

Comment: Ok @zygotelnit fixed after all. Was a facebook issue. Thanks thought. Sending over some karma points :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok was a facebook issue after all. Was solved after i posted this question to https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers